# Proving that the cubic polynomial $f(x)$ only has positive roots

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial and $x_{-}$ and $x_{+}$ are  two extrema of it such that

(i) $x_{+}> x_{-}>$$0$
(ii) $f(x_{-})$ $>0$ and $f(x_{+})$ $<0$
(iii)$f(0)<0$,

then all the three roots of $f(x)$ are positive.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0) < 0$ and $f(x_{-}) > 0$, by the intermediate value theorem, one of the roots, $x_1$ satisfies: $0 < x_1 < x_{-}$. Since the first extremum is $x_{-}$, $x_1$ is the only root between $0$ and $x_{-}$.

Next, similarly, since $f(x_{-}) > 0$ and $f(x_{+}) < 0$, by the intermediate value theorem, another root, $x_2$, satisfies $0 < x_{-} < x_2 < x_{+}$.

Finally, since $x_{+}$ is the biggest extremum and $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing between the two extrema (since $f(x_{-}) > 0$ and $f(x_{+}) < 0$) $f(x)$ monotonically increases for $x > x_{+}$. This means that the third root will be $0 < x_{+} < x_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0) < 0$ and $f(x_{-}) > 0$, by the intermediate value theorem $f$ has a root between $0$ and $x_{-} > 0$. The second root lies between $x_{-}$ and $x_{+}$ for the same reason.

The third root is positive as well: by studying the behaviour of $f'$ we conclude that since $f$ is decreasing between $x_{-}$ and $x_{+}$, it must be increasing for $x > x_{+}$. Then there exists an $\hat x$ such that $\hat x > x_{+}$ and $f(\hat x) > 0$. So, applying the intermediate value theorem again, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Cubic equations have at most 3 roots.

$f(x_+)<0, f(x_-)>0 \implies$ there is a root between $x_-$ and $x_+$

$f(x_-)>0, f(0)<0, \implies$ a root lies between $0$ and $x_-$

$0<x_-<x_+$ places 2 roots in $(0,x_+).  Where is the last one?

$f(0)<0,f(x_-)>0, f(x_+)>0 \implies f(x_-)$ is a maximum.

$f(x_+)$ is local minimum.

$f(x_+)<0$ and $f(x_+)$ is a local minimum $\implies$ There is one root to the right of x_+.

Comment: Is the reverse true?

Comment: @m.bubu The reverse of what?

Comment: I mean for positive roots $f(x)$ should satisfy all the three conditions.

Comment: It would could be the case that $f(0)>0, f(x_-)<0, f(x_+)>0$ and you would have 3 positive roots.